# Obtaining a generic bidirectional iterator from a vector

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Before writing a function that takes a generic bidirectional iterator I wanted to test out how it works for a vector of ints.

```
vector<int> a(10,1);
iterator<bidirectional_iterator_tag, int> i = a.begin();
for (; i != a.end(); ++i) cout << *i;
```

This code soes not compile. g++ complains you cannot convert the return type of begin() to `iterator<bidirectional_iterator_tag, int>` and that  the operators `++` and `*` are not defined on it. Obviously I am doing something wrong, would appreciate help.

Comment: [This article](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html) could prove interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although `std::iterator` is a base class which eases implementation of new iterators, not all iterators are implemented using this, and not all iterators convert to this. The only requirement for an iterator class is that it provides a given set of operations. No class hierarchy is implied by this, and most containers ship their own iterator classes. So in this case, you should use `vector<int>::iterator` as the type of your iterator. Or, if you are using the recent C++11 standard, you may use `auto` to let the compiler infer the type.

Comment: Does that mean I cannot pass a `vector<>::iterator` to a function which takes accepts a generic bidirectional iterator ? That would be rather disappointing. I tried casting, that did not work either.

Comment: @san, How about a template? Of course you'd have to ensure the passed iterator has at least the capabilities you need.

Comment: @chris Yes that will work. I was hoping by restricting what the types could be I will get more informative error messages.

Comment: @san, I guess specialization could do that, couldn't it?

Comment: The STL way is to pass iterators to templates. You could create a wrapper hierarchy where you have an abstract template `basic_iterator<int>` providing the common interface, and use that as the base class for a `concrete_iterator<std::vector<int>::iterator>` template to wrap the STL iterator. Doing so, you'd turn compile-time duck-typing into runtime polymorphism. In most cases, this will cost you performance but might save memory as you might need fewer specializations. You'd still need to pass things as references to preserve polymorphism.

Comment: @san, the standard algorithms are implemented as templates so that they don't need a common base type for the iterator. You should do the same.

Comment: @chris If you could show me how, I would be happy to upvote. What I had was `iterator<bidirectional_iteratir_tag, V>` as the type of the input argument so that invoking it on anything other than an iterator would elicit an error message. But now I realize it will disallow many legitimate iterators.

Comment: if you want to check whether something is an iterator, you could use `iterator_traits` and static assertions of one form or another. (C++ has them in the core language, boost provides portable mechanisms.)

Comment: @MvG, Good point. I forgot about using `static_assert` for that.

Comment: @san, It probably isn't the best fit here, but if you're still interested in learning, here's [an article on specialization](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html).